# Gdrive API does not detect all files in the selected folder when downloading

Tags: python, google-api

I have the following code which react not as I would like. I want to download the last file created/uploaded into the folder. The uploaded files are all CSV. I realized that it did not download the last one. So trying to understand, I realized that it detects the last file properly only if I open it once in the bowser. Then the code work and the file is detected. Any contribution would be appreciated.

```
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
folder_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFW4-YY" 

results = team_drive.DRIVE.files().list(pageSize=1, fields="files(createdTime,name,id)", orderBy="createdTime desc", q="'" + folder_id + "' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'", supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
```

For example, if I read the first 1 files as per the code above. I will get:

```
{'files': [{'id': '1-dI4MOuqknn9-R324cTI658EhVayM98niNlrxMblvoU', 'name': 'Balance-2020-07-11', 'createdTime': '2020-07-11T02:46:04.180Z'}
```

But there is a file which more recently created as of July 12th. It is not detected...

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether your all files have the correct mimeType, when you want to retrieve the CSV file, how about modifying from `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'` to `mimeType = 'text/csv'`? And also, for example, although I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason of your issue, when `orderBy="modifiedTime desc"` is modified to `orderBy="createdTime desc"`, the result will be changed?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you, I tried your solutions but unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I apologize that my proposal was not useful for your situation. From your replying and updating question, I have 3 questions. 1. I cannot understand about `For example, if I read the first 3 files as per the code above. I will get:  the 3rd day should be 2020-07-07 as the file in Gdrive. I can see it..`. Can I ask you about the detail of your situation and goal? 2. In your case, which do you want to confirm the modified time or the created time of the files? 3. In your current script, the XLSX files are retrieved. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike 1. I meant that the file are sorted by `createdTime desc`. This means that I should have July 9, July 8, July 7. But instead I have July 9, July 8, July 2. I assume it is because July 7 was uploaded to Drive but never opened after. My goal is to have the last uploaded file which correspond also to the current day (july 9 at the time i post this). 2. The latest created_time should be the date to select. 3. I don't understand your question.  One interesting thing I noticed also, is when I open a csv file in the GDRIVE browser, it create automatically a G spreadsheet with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. About `This means that I should have July 9, July 8, July 7. But instead I have July 9, July 8, July 2. I assume it is because July 7 was uploaded to Drive but never opened after`, in this case, what file do you want to download? If it's "July 9", I thought that the script can retrieve it. How about this? 2. From `The latest created_time should be the date to select.`, in this case, I think `modifiedTime` is suitable. 3. In the current script, the XLSX files are searched. In your question, I understood the CSV files are used. So I asked about this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your answer. I realized that my post what not clear. Could you read it again please? i have reformulated my issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. When the file list is retrieved with `createdTime desc`, the order of files follow the created time even when the older file has been modified after newer file was uploaded. From this situation, I'm worry that `createdTime desc` might have not be used for testing. Because your sample result values are different from the result retrieved with your provided script. Could you please confirm about this again? I would like to think of the solution after I could correctly understand about your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I am 100% sure of what I wrote. I checked again

Comment: @Tanaike Is it possible that the guy uploading files is missing to do something? Metadata related?

Comment: Thank you for replying and checking it again. But I saw your updated question, I think that your script cannot retrieve the result value. Because there is no value of `created_atTime` in `fields`. In your case, I think that an error occurs at `fields`. On the other hand, the returned value is shown in your question. So I cannot understand about your current situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, I manage to get the correct output by changing the mime type AND removing the fields. Because I tried to change the mime type before but it did not work. I am not really able to explain how I did, which is sad... Anyways, you put me on the right track with your comments...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I deeply apologize that I couldn't correctly understand about your situation and resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the correct output with the following code:

```
results = team_drive.DRIVE.files().list(pageSize=1, orderBy="createdTime desc", q="'" + folder_id + "' in parents and mimeType = 'text/csv'", supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).exec$
print(results)
```